# How should I read a text file without getting FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, file-io, computer-science, filenotfoundexception, file-read

I am coding a Word Search Generator program for a final assignment for my computer science class.

I have created a text file called "Words" which contains 10 words for each of the 26 letters in the alphabet. I am referring to this text file by reading it and store the words in an Array List.

I have used the feedback I've gotten here and made some changes. I have defined what `fileName` is, and I have inserted the exact location of my text file.

Here is my updated code:

```
public static List<String> readWords () throws IOException {

        String fileName = ("C:\\Users\\Dell\\workspace\\Final Summative\\src\\Words.txt");

        int maxLength = Math.max(rows, cols);

        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>(); // The words from the Words text file will be stored in this array list

        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName))) {      

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

                String s = sc.next().trim().toLowerCase();

                if (s.matches("^[a-z]{3," + maxLength + "}$")) { // We will pick only words with length = 3 and max. length, and [a-z] inside

                    words.add(s.toUpperCase());

                }//end of if

            }//end of while loop

        } catch (IOException e) {

            // Manage the error!

            e.printStackTrace();

        }//end of catch

        return words;

    }//end of readWords(fileName)
```

I am getting a `FileNotFoundException`when I run my code now. I have double checked that my text file is in a correct folder, but I am still having this error. It says this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dell\workspace\Final Summative\src\Words.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at WordSearch.readWords(WordSearch.java:76)
```

Comment: It is really your responsibility to do some debugging work before you post, and to highlight exactly where in the code the problem might be.

Comment: `fileName` is pointing to an incorrect location. You just need to fix that.

Comment: Tip: you need to place the file "somewhere accessible" to your program – easiest way: somewhere in the Java `CLASSPATH`. That's what that `FileNotFoundException` is telling you. What's the folder structure of your "project"? And where is the `Words` file located at?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did debug my code. The problem is the try-catch statement. My code is not "trying" the (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName))) part. It skips the try statement and directly jumps to the catch statement.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Oh...what exactly do you mean by "incorrect location?" I`m sorry, I`m just a high school student and still a beginner, so I`m not a pro at File I/O.

Comment: @YashviShah `fileName` is not a valid path. You haven't told us where the file is on your system, or what `fileName` is, so there's only so much we'll be able to help you with. You just need to verify the path of the file that you're trying to read though. What's the path to the file you're trying to read? What's `fileName`?

Comment: @x80486 The program itself and the text file are located under the same file. It is under workplace/Final Summative/src specifically.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Oh! Right, that. Well, what if I do this: fileName = ("C:\\Users\\Dell\\workspace\\Final Summative\\src\\Word.txt");

Comment: @YashviShah I don't know, because I don't know the actual path of the file you're trying to read. You'll just need to verify that they match.

Comment: *`// Manage the error!`* Don't just comment on it, change that `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Try writing a file to the location instead. If successful search for it. If not you probably have a directory error. Then try creating the directory before creating the file. If successful search for the file. Observe its location compared to where you thought it was and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you haven't closed brackets { } correctly in `s.matches("^[a-z]{3," + maxLength + "]$"`.
And most likely filename isn't correctly given.
Check if it's something like: `readWords("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/words.txt")` in case your text file is on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If all you really need to do is read all the lines in the file then there is a shortcut in more modern versions of Java: `Files.lines`.

In fact if you have a pattern that matches words then you could use `Matcher.results` and `MatchResult.group` to do it all in one go:

```
Files.lines(path)
    .map(pattern::matcher)
    .flatMap(Matcher::results)
    .map(MatchResult::group)
    .collect(Collector.toList());
```

However I'm not sure if you've studied streams yet or which libraries you're allowed to use.

Note that I've collected to a list here though it probably makes more sense to collect to a set (assuming you don't need to know about duplicates) or to a map (with first letter as key if that's important to the use of the words).